# Uniqueness of Algebraic Belyi Pairs from Dessin

Tags: algebraic-geometry, field-theory, galois-theory, riemann-surfaces, galois-representations

From a Dessin d'Enfant on a surfaces $X$ we get a meromorphic function $f:X\rightarrow\mathbb{CP}^{1}$ such that the only critical values are $\{0,1,\infty\}$ i.e a Belyi pair $(X,f)$.

Belyi's theorem says that from this we get a Belyi pair $(X',f')$ where $X'$ and $f'$ are in fact defined over $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ and isomorphic to $(X,f)$ over $\mathbb{C}$.

Is this pair the unique (up to composing $f$ with automorphisms of $X$) pair over $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$? I've seen this described in various places but want to know why this is true.

I'm trying to understand how $Gal(\overline{\mathbb{Q}},\mathbb{Q})$ acts on Dessin and don't have enough basic algebraic geometry to see that there are not choices on $(X',f')$ that could make this undefined.

Comment: Yes, there is a bijection between Belyi pairs (up to isomorphism) and dessins d'enfants (up to equivalence, i.e., orientation-preserving homeomorphism). This is stated in Theorem 4.25 of Girondo and González-Diez's [*Introduction to Compact Riemann Surfaces and Dessins d'Enfants*](https://books.google.com/books/about/Introduction_to_Compact_Riemann_Surfaces.html?id=2SoLO_jknL4C).  The real content of the argument is Proposition 4.22(iii).

Comment: I can see this bijection for Belyi pairs defined over $\mathbb{C}$, is it obvious it extends to Belyi pairs over $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$? The reference seems to work over $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: I'm still not sure exactly what you're asking to be defined over $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$. Suppose $(X_1, f_1)$ and $(X_2, f_2)$ are Belyi pairs defined over $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ both corresponding to the same dessin. By the theorem, then they are isomorphic over $\mathbb{C}$, so there is an isomorphism $\sigma: X_1 \to X_2$ such that $f_2 \circ \sigma = f_1$. Are you asking if $\sigma$ is defined over $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$?

Comment: Yeah sorry so I guess my response didn't explain my question. I want to know whether once given two models over $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ which are isomorphic over $\mathbb{C}$ if we act on both with an element of $Gal(\overline{\mathbb{Q}}/\mathbb{Q})$ are they still isomorphic over $\mathbb{C}$.